# AIDL, Interface Callback, EventBus, Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, interface, ipc, aidl, event-bus

Am creating music player.There is a service to stream music in background
For the activity to service and from service to activity which mechanism, i should use ? Now i am using green robot EventBus and AIDL. In EventBus which one is better ? My app works fine, but issue is that simultaneous multiple click causing ANR in app.

```
recyclerViewAdapterTwo = new RecyclerViewAdapterTwo(ActivityTwo.this, trackList, categoriesList, new MusicTracksRecyclerViewAdapterTwo.ViewHolderOnClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int id, MusicTracksRecyclerViewAdapterTwo.VHItem vh) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new PostSongListChangeToService(songDataList, position));
        }
    });
```

Comment: use "bound service" pattern (either as AIDL or "local bound service")

Comment: My app works fine, but issue is that simultaneous multiple click causing ANR in app.

Comment: with no code, i have no idea what "simultaneous multiple click" you  mean

Comment: now check code please

Comment: ok if you are using AIDL so why EventBus as well?

Comment: using aidl only for getting callback like music is playing or not, position, duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventBus, Interface callback both are good options. Don't use Broadcast Receivers for this.

Now for the ANR, could you please share some code as where/how are you processing the events. Other then that try to pre-process most of the data in background thread and then jump to Main Thread only to actually play/pause/skip etc.

PS: If you are using Handler to actually preform things on the MainThread, try not to post everything in one go, give your queue some time between msg/runnables to run. It may add a slight delay on button click but will not freeze your Activity/Service.

you can refer to the Otto here : http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Which eventbus is better ?

Comment: Any event bus would behave similarly for you. I have had a past experience with otto.

Answer (score 0):

If your Service and the Activity is in the same process you should not use AIDL,also BroadCast Receiver doesn't make any sense for this purpose.You can use an IntentService to achieve this functionality.

Comment: *You can use an IntentService to achieve this functionality.* for what exactly?

Comment: also, why shouldn't one use AIDL in that case?

Comment: By *process* you mean *Linux process*? Whats wrong with it please elaborate more and add citation.

Comment: IntentService stops itself when it runs out of work, i want to keep service to live in background

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option since for some time now Otto event bus is now deprecated in favour of RxJava. 
I suggest to try RxJava since it gives more flexibility and transparency about Thread swapping and also provides huge set or functional operations which makes code beautiful thus maintainable :)

There is a diffence in that you cannot easily post events from outside a provided stream to already subscribed consumer.

For that you can try [RHub](https://github.com/apptik/RHub) which enables this "Bus" feature.

You can check the [example app](https://github.com/apptik/RHub/tree/master/example-app/src/main/java/io/apptik/rhub/exampleapp)